# Facebook fan page without custom URL redirects to login unless already signed in

Tags: facebook-pages

I created a fan page for my business and since I don't have 25 people to create a unique URL, I'm using the "non-unique" URL (default Facebook URL).  I have provided the default Facebook page URL to my developers so that when users click the Facebook icon, they can go directly to my fan page.

However, instead of taking me directly to my fan page, it is redirecting users to the Facebook sign-in page instead of the fan page (if not already signed in).

Is the only way to go directly to a fan page based on having a unique username? Or is the default URL assigned at the creation of a fan page supposed to also allow direct access to the fan page?

Comment: Thank you both MarQ and Brandon ;-) That was exactly the issue, I did specify an age restriction and removing it allowed my link to go directly to my fan page.

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if you have an age restriction or any other restrictions set up that would prevent a user from accessing the URL without age/other verification.

Answer (score 3):

That issue is definitely based on age restrictions. Set the age restrictions to 13+ and the default Facebook generated URL page will appear to all users regardless of if they are logged in or not.

Comment: Awesome man, thnx a ton. :D

Answer (score 0):

As I have just found out after creating another page and then having to Merge the 2 together , you must also have country preference set to all.